# Unable to stash directory with multilevel directories/files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I've build created on one machine say `A` with directory structure like following at location `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/SVNCheckout/` -

```
-- Installer
  -- Build
    -- ReleaseKit 
      -- Installable
         -- Build
            -- A
            -- B
            -- C.xyz
         -- Installer 
           -- D
           -- E
           -- F.xyz 
     -- Temporary
        ....
```

Basically I've `Installer` directory which has multilevel directories/files. I want to copy`Installer` and paste it on another machine's location.

For stashing, I used following code(Note: I'm at location `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/SVNCheckout/` inside which `Installer` directory resides) -

```
stash allowEmpty: true, includes: '/Installer/*', name: 'Installer', useDefaultExcludes: false
```

When executed this, on Jenkins console, I see `Stashed 0 file(s)` message.

Could you please help how I would be able to `Installer` directory with all level directories and files inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build , as it follows ant regex - Omitting `*` or using `**` will probably make stash needy files you are looking for.

Also path I believe will be relative to Workspace. So I think you need to use exclude trailing `/`

```
stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'Installer/**', name: 'Installer', useDefaultExcludes: false
```

> **includes (optional)** Optional set of Ant-style include patterns. Use a
>   comma separated list to add more than one expression. If **blank**,
>   treated like **: all files. The current working directory is the base
>   directory for the saved files, which will later be restored in the
>   same relative locations, so if you want to use a subdirectory wrap
>   this in dir.

Comment: You're right, I should exclude `/` and have `**`. It worked and most importantly thanks for pointing to documentation link. I had searched for it a lot but could not find it!